# React-Native Navigation using navigation.navigate()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

i have a simple react native app and I need to navigate to a certain component (ViewDrafts) on button click.

i have tried this and many errors has shown

```
const App = ({ navigation }) => {
//some code written here.
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.body}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>
            Hi there! {"\n"}Welcome to Invoice Creator
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={toggleVisible}>
            <Text style={styles.content}>Create Invoice</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text></Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ViewDrafts.js")}
          >
            <Text style={styles.content}>View Drafts</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
...
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

As you can see here

```
 <TouchableOpacity
     style={styles.button}
     onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ViewDrafts.js")}
     >
    <Text style={styles.content}>View Drafts</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

but it is not working!
any ideas please?

Comment: Can you show us how you have initialized navigation ? the stacks n all so that we can help you

Comment: can you show us your navigation stack once, you need to give the component name in navigation stack, not the file name navigation.navigate("ViewDrafts")}

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the '[react-native-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)' documentation?

You navigate to the screen name, not to it file path.

It should look something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import ViewDrafts from './screens/ViewDrafts';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ViewDrafts" component={ViewDrafts} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And then you navigate to it like this:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
     style={styles.button}
     onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ViewDrafts")} // <--- CHANGED
 >
    <Text style={styles.content}>View Drafts</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: oh okay that should be it but i have one error.
Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider
is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: when i do that it gives this error
Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider
this error comes when i add the navigation or more specifically when i add
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
those two imports

Comment: did u added SafeAreaProvider in App.js??

Comment: No. Read the documentation and follow it. Any other way of implementing RN components is not good.